# Simple store connected list for dojo

Tags: dojo

Is there a simpler list type than DataGrid that can be connected to a store for Dojo?

I would like the data abstraction of the store, but I don't need the header and cell stucture. I would like to be more flexible in the representation of the datalines, where maybe each line calls an function to get laid out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask a really good question.  I actually have a blog post that is still in draft form called "The DataGrid should not be your first option".

I have done a couple thing using the store to display data from a store in a repeated form.

I have manually built an html table using dom-construct and for each.

```
var table = dojo.create('table', {}, parentNode);
var tbody = dojo.create('tbody', {}, table); // a version of IE needs this or it won't render the table

store.fetch({  // this is a dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore, but you cana dapt to the dojo.Store API
    query: {},
    onComplete: function(itms) {
        dojo.forEach(itms, function(itm, idx) {
            var tr = dojo.create('tr', {}, tbody);
            // use idx to set odd/even css class
            // create tds and the data that goes in them
        });
    }
});
```

I have also created a repeater, where I have an html template in a string form and use that to instantiate html for each row.

```
var htmlTemplate = '<div>${name}</div>'; // assumes name is in the data item
store.fetch({  // this is a dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore, but you cana dapt to the dojo.Store API
    query: {},
    onComplete: function(itms) {
        dojo.forEach(itms, function(itm, idx) {
            var expandedHtml = dojo.replace(htmlTemplate, itm);
            // use dojo.place to put the html where you want it
        });
    }
});
```

You could also have a widget that you instantiate for each item.

Comment: I have Gist that was part of a different blog post, that demonstrates some of this as well.  Toward the bottom, there is an fnDisplayOrders function that does some of the above. https://gist.github.com/2010137

Comment: yea, I think I will need to resort to such a solution. Still I think it a bit weird that dojo has all this abstract stores, and then lacks in widgets to use them..